# ga:visits showing zero when ga:pageviews, ga:visitors show values?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a top profileid and a filtered profileid.
the filtered profileid uses a path starting with /xxx/yyy/

now in site I have 2 view pages - 
1) top profile + my filter of /xxx/yyy/ 
2) sub profile

both pages show the same number and values for pages
but when I do a view of "ga:pageviews, ga:visitors, ga:visits"
I get different values only for visits (sometimes 0 on #1)
examples of output
1) 
70 5 1
40 8 0 <--how can I get a zero?
2)
70 5 6
40 8 8

so hitting the top profile and adding my filter to the call gives me invalid visits.
using the same code for profile #2 I get correct numbers.

looking inside google admin, profile 2 only has the 1 filter and it matches the same as what I am doing in code. also the pages match up so this does not make sense to me.

how is it possible to get numbers but have no visits?
is there a way to get an individual listing of the data that it is using to output to my filtered request?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/09/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-pages/

I think I figured this out. doing the filter inside google as a separate profile will retag the first page to a session count, whereas if I query the top profile and filter on my end I will get very low session starts because most people hit the home page or login page which counts as their session start.

it seems I cannot use the metric sessions or visits along with my filtering to a sub section.